# convert a simple temperature bash script to javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, bash

I have a bash script that spit out the cpu temperature in Beaglebon Black. I need to convert these to javascript. Any good at linux command and javascript have any idea how to do this ?

I was thinking of using fs.readfile command but not too sure.

Here the code in bash script and link of where i got it from:

[bash script link](http://inspire.logicsupply.com/2014/12/beaglebone-cpu-temperature-monitor.html)

```html
# CPU TEMP MONITOR
# CTRL-C TO STOP
# WRITTEN BY BRIAN HECKATHORNE - ME@GODFEAR.ORG 
# Modified by Richard St-Pierre - inspire.logicsupply.com
# Simple script for monitoring the CPU temp on a BeagleBone Black running Debian
  
#!/bin/bash
for (( ; ; ))
do
        echo -n "CPU Temp [Celsius]: "
        cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_input | sed 's/...$//'
        sleep 2
done
```

Comment: This `bash`-script should earn a [*useless use of `cat` award.*](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more-or-less literal port.

A few caveats:

- I infer that the file only has one line in it. If that's not correct, this code may need a tweak.
- This is a more-or-less literal port, meaning that I make no judgments about whether `cat` (and, therefore, `fs.readFileSync()`), regexp replacement, etc., are the best choices here. I'm just mapping the bash code to Node.js code, more or less.

With that out of the way, here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');

var temperatureFile = '/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_input';

var displayTemperature = function () {
    process.stdout.write("CPU Temp [Celsius]: ");
    process.stdout.write(fs.readFileSync(temperatureFile, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
        .replace(/...$/g, '\n'));
}

displayTemperature();
setInterval(displayTemperature, 2000);
```